# Form Collection how to avoid creating duplicate record (OneToMany - ManyToOne)

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, symfony4, formcollection

**The problem**

I have two entities, one called `Question` that can be self-referencing, it has an association with `QuestionSubQuestions` (it was necessary to add some extra fields like `filter`)  so it can have Many questions, but the same questions can be used as children in many `Questions`. The intention of it is to have a single entity that can have many `Children` (Questions) and re-using the existing ones.

The problem I'm facing is that when I add an existing Question as a child, it creates a new `Question` record in the database instead of using the existing record for the association.

I have a web interface where the user can pick form a list of existing questions and add it as a child to the main one. The form POST all the info (including the id of the entity) and doctrine process it by itself.

Everything is saved and removed correctly when adding non-existing questions (new ones) but when picking an existing one makes the mentioned error. But this doesn't happen when the Question gets updated, doctrine persists the existing relations correctly and the create duplicated records don't appear.

Also, the controller doesn't contain anything special, but when dumping the form's data I can see that the added question doesn't have the `__isInitialized__` property, so I can guess doctrine doesn't really know that that entity already exist. You can see in the dump (see code section) that child with index 0 has the parameter and the one with index 1 doesn't.

**The question**

So, how I can fix this? Maybe is there a way to check if the entity exists while processing the form data and attach the entity again to the EntityManager? I know I can make a Listener for that, but I don't know if is a good practice.

**Any** help will be apreciated.

**The actual code**

Form data dump:

```
Question^ {#1535 ▼
  -id: 56
  -question: "TestB1"
  -children: PersistentCollection^ {#1562 ▼
    -owner: Question^ {#1535}
    -association: array:15 [ …15]
    -em: EntityManager^ {#238 …11}
    -isDirty: true
    #collection: ArrayCollection^ {#1563 ▼
      -elements: array:3 [▼
        0 => QuestionSubQuestion^ {#1559 ▼
          -question: Question^ {#1535}
          -subQuestion: Question^ {#1592 ▼
            +__isInitialized__: true
            -id: "57"
            -question: "P-1"
          }
          -filter: "affirmative"
        }
        1 => QuestionSubQuestion^ {#2858 ▼
          -question: Question^ {#1535}
          -subQuestion: Question^ {#2863 ▼
            -id: "57"
            -question: "P-1"
          }
          -filter: "negative"
        }
      ]
    }
    #initialized: true
  }
}
```

`Question.php`

```php
class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $id;

    ...

    /**
     * @var ArrayCollection
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="QuestionSubQuestion", mappedBy="question", fetch="EAGER" ,cascade={"persist"}, orphanRemoval=true)
     */
    private $children;

    ...

    /**
     * @param QuestionSubQuestion $children
     */
    public function addChild(QuestionSubQuestion $children): void
    {
        if ($this->children->contains($children)) {
            return;
        }

        $children->setQuestion($this);
        $this->children->add($children);
    }

    /**
     * @param mixed $children
     */
    public function removeChild(QuestionSubQuestion $children): void
    {
        if (!$this->children->contains($children)) {
            return;
        }

        $this->children->removeElement($children);
        // needed to update the owning side of the relationship!
        $children->setSubQuestion(null);
    }

}
```

`QuestionSubQuestion.php`

```php
class QuestionSubQuestion
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="children", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", cascade={"persist"})
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $subQuestion;

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false)
     */
    private $filter;
}
```

Form `QuestionType.php`

```php
class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('question')
            ->add('children', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => SubQuestionEmbeddedForm::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype_name' => '__subQuestion__',
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Question::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Embedded form `SubQuestionEmbeddedForm.php`

```php
class SubQuestionEmbeddedForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('subQuestion', SubQuestionType::class)
            ->add('filter', HiddenType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => QuestionSubQuestion::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

`SubQuestionType.php`

```php
class SubQuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('id', HiddenType::class, [
                'required' => false,
            ])->add('question', TextType::class, [
                'label' => false,
            ])
            ->add('country', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('category', HiddenType::class)
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Question::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Edit controller

```php
$question = $questionRepository->find($questionId);

$form = $this->createForm(QuestionType::class, $question);
$form->handleRequest($request);

if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
    $question = $form->getData();

    $questionRepository->save($question);

    return $this->redirect($request->getUri());
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure to understand, but i think you would like to create a tree of question. You don't need SubQuestion class, and children of Question is Question too. I am right ?

Comment: @threeside Yes, SubQuestion is not a existing class but it's the same Question class that can have many Question children. The reason behind that is to add some additional fields (not only ids) in the relation model. Since you can't make a ManyToMany with extra fields, I had to make an OneToMany (Question->QuestionSubQuestion) and ManyToOne (QuestionSubQuestion->Question). That part of the entire form is working properly, the issue is when adding an existing question as child, I want to doctrine pick the id of the posted question and link the two entities, not creating a new Question record.

Comment: Ok, i understand now. You don't show your SubQuestionType, Have you got the possibility to add new question as child directly in SubQuestionType or simply use existing Question ?

Comment: @threeside Sorry, I just added the form type. Yes, in the interface I have a button using the HTML prototype of the `children` field so I can add a new child with new unique data. But, I also have a select list made with twig where I pick the id of the question I want and manually with Javascript add the question to the collection using the prototype from the other button and then passing the data to the inputs, even the id. Then I block the fields to avoid data manipulation, since it should contain the same data as the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Test this if problem was resolved : (I add title field in Question Entity, change this by your text identification field or remove)

```
class QuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('title', TextType::class)

            ->add('children', CollectionType::class, [
                'entry_type' => QuestionSubQuestionType::class,
                'allow_add' => true,
                'allow_delete' => true,
                'label' => false,
                'by_reference' => false,
                'prototype'    => true,
                'prototype_name' => '__subQuestion__',
            ]);
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Question::class,
        ));
    }
}






class QuestionSubQuestionType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('subQuestion', EntityType::class, [
                'label' => false,
                    'class'    => 'YourBundle:Question',
                    'choice_label' => 'title',

                    'multiple' => false,
                    'expanded'  => false,
                    /* use query builder to customize choices
                    'query_builder' => function (MaterialRepository $er) {
                        return $er->getQbOrderBy('m.id', 'DESC');
                     },*/

                ))
             ->add('filter', HiddenType::class)

            /* uncomment if these fields are in SubQuestion Entity
            ->add('country', HiddenType::class)
            ->add('category', HiddenType::class)
            */
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => QuestionSubQuestion::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it's better to use only existing result in your subQuestionFormType. In your case, i use $ajax request to add new Question and add it to list in subQuestionType.

Comment: Thanks for your time, I'll try your solution.